# Exclude certain users (e.g. `is_admin?`) from ahoy tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I'm trying to create a rule using ahoy's [exclude method](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#exclusions) to exclude admin users from tracking [as suggested in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/205).

But I can't figure out how to get the `User` object when I only have the `controller` and `request`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/README.md#how-it-works), in your controller, (or ApplicationController), you can skip the action used to track a visit:

```rb
skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit, if: :your_method_here?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude every visit and event from being tracked based on your condition, you can access `current_user` in your `config/initializers/ahoy.rb`:

```
Ahoy.exclude_method = lambda do |controller, request|
  user = controller.current_user

  user.present? && user.is_admin?
end
```

Note: When this method returns true, no tracking takes place throughout the app.

Prevent certain Rails actions from creating visits:

```
skip_before_action :track_ahoy_visit, if: -> { current_user.is_admin? }
```

If anyone wants to just skip specific event:

```
ahoy.track('viewed_book', title: 'Hot, Flat, and Crowded') unless current_user.is_admin?
```

To keep events and visits tracked data for admins while excluding them from query results, you can create a scope in the `Visit` model to exclude admins:

```
scope :actual_visits, -> { where('user_id IS NULL OR user_id NOT IN (?)', User.where(is_admin: true).ids) }
```